# How to adapt a paper to the Tex style of a journal

Tags: templates, revtex, ctan, journal

I want to write my paper using LaTeX. In [this journal](http://publishing.aip.org/authors/preparing-your-manuscript) they provide their LaTeX file which you can download from the link. [Here is the readme file.](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=66153167961327255998)
I do not understand several things. I use Windows.

1- I do not know if I have to install the files somehow in the LaTeX or if they are ready.

2- I do not understand this part of the readme file:

```
Not Included   
------------
The following packages are required by REVTeX but are not
included in this distribution. Please obtain from CTAN
(Comprehensive TeX Archive Network), e.g. <http://www.ctan.org/>. Direct
links to the necessary files can be found at <http://authors.aps.org/revtex4/>.

natbib.dtx   - Version 8.31a or later; found in latex/contrib/natbib on CTAN
natbib.ins   - LaTeX this to create natbib.sty and natbib
               documentation from natbib.dtx
bm.dtx       - Bold math style - part of (current!) standard LaTeX2e tools
bm.sty       - generated from bm.dtx by running tools.ins
textcase.dtx - Found in latex/contrib/textcase on CTAN
textcase.ins - LaTeX this to generate textcase.sty from textcase.dtx
url.sty      - Found in latex/contrib/misc on CTAN

An up-to-date installation of AMS-LaTeX is also required for certain
documentclass options. Version 2.0 or higher is needed. It is
available from <http://www.ams.org/tex/>.
```

2a - They say that I should find `natbib.dtx` in `latex/contrib/natbib` on CTAN. I cannot find such a place on the [CTAN website](http://www.ctan.org).

2b- I do not know how to install any of these in Windows. Their respective readme files are confusing and not clear.

Does anybody have experience on this issue and can help me?

**Edit**

When I run the `reftest4-1` file in `revtex4-1\revtex4-1-tds\tex\latex\revtex` I get this error:

```
! Emergency stop.
<read 0> 

l.87 ...ilename]{Type in file name (no extension)}
```

Comment: If you have installed TeX, you almost certainly have all of those installed already. If not, use MikTeX's package manager or TeX Live's to install them. You don't need to get them directly from CTAN (and it is better not to).

Comment: Why are you uploading a readme file to a third party server instead of just linking to the zip file?

Comment: @Johannes_B I linked the zip file too. I thought someone would not like to download the file so I uploaded separately. However, it does not open in the browser as I expected.

Comment: [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137)

Answer (score 4):

The fact that the README file contains the locution

> An up-to-date installation of AMS-LaTeX is also required

and points the reader to a non-CTAN website strongly suggests that the instructions haven't been updated in a decade, and maybe quite a bit longer. (The last time I recall seeing the `amsmath` package being referred to as `AMS-LaTeX` was long before the hairs on my head started turning gray... Ah, the good old days... I digress...) Similarly, the most recent version of `natbib` since at least 2010 has been 8.31b, not 8.31a as claimed in the README file.

Not to worry, though: If the vintage of *your* TeX installation is more recent than ca. 2001, all packages that are mentioned in the instructions should be installed and available automatically.

Comment: Oh right, location doesn't make any sense. Sorry :-) I *never* heard locution before, so thanks for teaching me something new. I'll delete the comment :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B - I had deliberately chosen a term that's somewhat obsolete, as a gloss on the obsolete material in the README file. However, I may have overdone it a bit... :-)